# how to diagnose/fix chrome pop up warning to change password due to a data breach

Tags: google-chrome, security, passwords, password-protection

I'm currently running an app on AWS elastic beanstalk, and recently I had an issue come up where when I tried to enter a password, this a google chrome pop up appeared that is the same as the image below. The password is encrypted and entered in a password-type field. I know this is a very general question, but would anyone have any advice in diagnosing why this issue came about (perhaps by looking at specific things in AWS console), and how to prevent it? Does this warning occur only when the user has entered a password that is common/used across multiple apps, and has nothing to do with the code the app is based on?
[image: Chrome-data-breach-pop-up]

Answer (score 0):

Searched and found this answer:

**Important: You must be signed in to Chrome to get these notifications.**

To start or **stop** notifications:

On your computer, open Chrome.
At the top right, click More More and then Settings.
Under "Privacy and security," click Security.
Select a safe browsing option: Enhanced protection or Standard protection.
*Tip: This feature is only available if "Safe Browsing" is turned on.*

Comment: but as a developer how would I actually know how any data breaches are occurring (if any)?